# Return as new JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I have a set a returned object like this:

```
table A: true
table B: true
table C: ""
value A: "AB"
value B: "CD"
value C: ""
```

In a form, table A - C are checkbox, values are input belongs to the checkbox. Is there a way to return the checkbox with true condition and value together as a new JSON object like this?

```
 "newRecord": "[{\"table\": \"table A *,table B *\",\"parameters\": \"AB, CD\"}
```

From my understanding, I will need to loop through the checked box, and for every true condition, find the value and push both into the newRecord as a new object with value as the parameter.

New to this, trying to come out with this chunk of code, not sure how to make it work

```
 let result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.newForm.value));
  this.newForm.value.checkboxSelection.forEach((element) => {
        if(element.checkboxSelection === true) {
          result.newRecord[index].push();
        }
 });
```

Comment: Don't call `JSON.stringify` until you are done building up the result. Never manually modify JSON strings.

Comment: Your words make sense, but the code is a bit confusing. Could you provide some sample html of the table? Or the stringified version of your return object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
const data = {
  'table A': true,
  'table B': true,
  'table C': "",
  'value A': "AB",
  'value B': "CD",
  'value C': "",
};

const result = Object.keys(data).reduce((acc, key) => {
  if (!data[key]) return acc;

  const group: string = key.split(' ')[0];

  if (acc[group]) acc[group] += (', ' + key);
  else acc[group] = key;

  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

prints

```
{table: "table A, table B", value: "value A, value B"}
```

See https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-jgyqyu?file=index.ts